# Choppy/Laggy scrolling of Collection View with Dynamic Content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am having a problem where my collection view scrolling becomes very choppy/laggy as I get more and more cells. The screen contains a list of messages and comments for the messages, so every single view is dynamically sized. I have a bunch of custom layout attributes which I apply to handle laying and sizing everything.

I apply the custom attributes to the cells by overriding applyLayoutAttributes: and then calculate all the subviews frames from those.

I already cache the calculated sizes of cells but it is not enough.

I assume that there are some techniques people use to address this problem, like caching layout attributes, or somehow preventing the need to layout a cells subviews everytime cellForRow is called?

I assume this is a common problem since it is a problem I have faced with literally every table I make with dynamic content? I would appreciate any ideas :)

P.S. Rasterizing the cells doesn't help.